# Python- Implementing pagination function using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scraping titles from this webpage https://www.opensubtitles.org/en/search/sublanguageid-all I am getting the titles but couldn't figure out the pagination layer. I tried to implement the pagination:

```
from typing import List
import httpx
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "authority": "www.opensubtitles.org",
    "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7",
    "accept-language": "en,ru;q=0.9",
    "cache-control": "max-age=0",
    # 'cookie': '_ga=GA1.2.2026298587.1682033738; _gid=GA1.2.838139868.1682033738; searchform=formname%3Dsearchform%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C1%7C%7C%7C1%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C; PHPSESSID=bA2jNCdwZ6WA5uUzeiGsDqCCFS3',
    "referer": "https://www.opensubtitles.org/en/search/subs",
    "sec-ch-ua": '"Chromium";v="110", "Not A(Brand";v="24", "YaBrowser";v="23"',
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "sec-ch-ua-platform": '"Linux"',
    "sec-fetch-dest": "document",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "navigate",
    "sec-fetch-site": "none",
    "sec-fetch-user": "?1",
    "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 YaBrowser/23.3.1.906 (beta) Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36",
}

def initial_request(url):
    print(f"HTTP POST request to URL: {url}", end="\n")
    with httpx.Client(headers=headers) as client:
        resp = client.get(url)
        print(f" | Status Code: {resp.status_code}")
        return resp


def pagination(response, ignore_titles: List[str]):
    while True:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
        next_page = soup.select_one(
            "#msg > span:nth-child(2) > b:nth-child(2) > a"
        ).get("href")

        if next_page:
            next_url = "https://www.opensubtitles.org" + next_page
            print(f"HTTP GET request to URL: {next_url}", end="\n")
            next_response = httpx.get(next_url, headers=headers)
            print(f" | Status Code: {next_response.status_code}")
            parse_titles(next_response, ignore_titles)
        else:
            break


def parse_titles(response, ignore_titles: List[str]):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    raw_titles = [t.get("title") for t in soup.select("a.bnone")]
    clean_t = list(filter(None, [t for t in raw_titles]))
    parsed_titles = [
        t.replace('"', "").replace("subtitles -", "").strip()
        for t in clean_t
        if t.startswith("subtitles")
    ]
    json_data = json.dumps(
        {"Titles": [t for t in parsed_titles if t not in ignore_titles]}, indent=2
    )
    print(json_data)
    
    pagination(response, ignore_titles)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ignore_titles = [
        "Better Call Saul Point and Shoot",
        "My Sister's Serial Killer Boyfriend",
    ]
    base_url = "https://www.opensubtitles.org/en/search/sublanguageid-all"
    init_response = initial_request(base_url)
    pagination(init_response, ignore_titles)
```

the above code is not doing pagination correctly for example it is skipping the first `https://www.opensubtitles.org/en/search/sublanguageid-all` page totally and start scrpaing data with `https://www.opensubtitles.org/en/search/sublanguageid-all/offset-40`. Can anyone help me figuring this issue out?

Comment: As I can see this site is down at the moment. If you open it says "Site will be online soon. We are doing some necessary backups and upgrades. Thanks for understanding".